# Rewrite URL in Custom Logs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have defined a rewrite URL in `http.conf` to append a parameter to the request URL. In the Custom Log output I am not seeing the modified request URL. When I looked at the cause I found in one of the forums that `mod_rewrite` only affects accesses invoked via HTTP and does not affect file operations inside the server. Is that true and is there any way to log only the modified rewrite URL in the Apache logs? Your help is much appreciated.

The sample URL I am trying to access is `http://www.abc.com/pixel.gif?on=test` and in the output I want something like `/pixel.gif?type=modified&on=test`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.abc\.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$    /$1?type=modified       [QSA,L]
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to log rewrite-related things if you turn on the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive.

Basically, you would be adding this to your .htaccess file *(and the log path may vary)*:

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

But note, that `RewriteLogLevel` can really slow down your development or production server.  You might want to use a smaller number... instead of `5`.  And when you are done checking your `RewriteRule`s... you will most likely want to comment out (or delete,) the `RewriteLog`/`RewriteLogLevel` lines.

Hope that helps with your debugging!

Comment: Thanks summea. I cannot change RewriteLogLevel to 5, as you said it will bump my server. I will look for a different approach to add the parameter. All I wanted to know whether is their a way to showcase the rewrite url only in access log and I see that their no way to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem; and also, I think (though I have to find the reference for this thought,) that mod_rewrite will only work on the URL when the URL is being accessed over HTTP, like you were thinking.  But I still have to double-check on that...

Comment: I found the information in one of the forum - http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/2858.htm but not sure how reliable it is.